# R - ggplot sort x axis by acsending - factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a bar plot using ggplot. code below:

```
ggplot(foo, aes(thisCol1IsAFactor, Col2, fill = Col3)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position   = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

I would like to sort the *thisCol1IsAFactor* by ascending order; having it increase along the x axis.  The thisCol1IsAFactor  column is in order like this:

```
7/31/2017
7/31/2017
7/31/2017
7/31/2017
8/7/2017
8/7/2017
8/7/2017
8/7/2017
```

There are duplicate dates as each observation has its own date.  The bar plot works and looks great, except the sorting/ordering makes it a bit difficult to read.  The dates do not get displayed in chronological order along the x axis.

Comment: Maybe convert the date column to an actual date object using `as.Date()` (pay attention to the format argument!). Also, there is `geom_col` that is specifically to save you from typing `stat = "identity"` with `geom_bar`.

Comment: I will try that! ty!

Comment: that did not work.. it put a space between the bars and did not list the dates

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this function:

scale_x_discrete(thisCol1IsAFactor)

```
ggplot(foo, aes(thisCol1IsAFactor, Col2, fill = Col3)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position   = "dodge") + 
scale_x_discrete(thisCol1IsAFactor) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Factors are automatically ordered in alphabetical order (treating numbers as character strings) - that's why the ordering is poor.  You need to treat them as dates.  Try

```
library(tidyverse)

foo %>%
mutate(
  Col1AsDate = as.Date(thisCol1IsAFactor, "%m/%d/%Y")
) %>%
ggplot(aes(Col1AsDate, Col2, fill = Col3)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position   = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

You can also manually reorder all the factors, but this is a lot easier.